# Function Parameter Not Correctly Adding to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

In my game that I am creating, I have a function that takes the name and amount of an item, and adds it to the JSON "Player Invetory".

The code is as following:

```
function inventory(addOrRemove, item, amount) {
console.log(item);
    if (addOrRemove == 'add') {
        if (player.inventory.item== undefined) {
            player.inventory.item= amount;
        } else {
            player.inventory.item= player.inventory.item+ amount;
        }
    } 
console.log(player.inventory)
}
```

The output, when calling the function in this manner is as follows:

```
inventory('add','coin',10)
// In the console log on line 2, "item" is defined as "coin"
// The player invetory object as called for in the console on line 10 has one value, "item: 10"
```

Now, the problem is that it will not add to the array based on the function parameter. I want the player inventory object to be "player.inventory.coin: 10" instead of "player.inventory.item: 10". The same applies for any items, so that the inventory dynamically can add any type of unique item.

I looked for other similar questions but was unable to find anyone with the same problem as myself, although maybe that is because I'm not entirely sure what this problem is called myself, but I did put in the effort and am stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the `item` variable to your `inventory` object like this:

```
player.inventory[item] = amount;
```

This will use the string `'coin'` in the `item` variable and set that as a key in the `inventory` object:

```
player.inventory['coin'] = amount;
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand better now. Thank you for the explanation as well as how to fix it! I applied your solution and it worked. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if (player.inventory[item] == undefined) {
     player.inventory[item] = amount;
} else {
    player.inventory[item] = player.inventory[item] + amount;
    // or: player.inventory[item] += amount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how simple the solution often is. I'll accept the other answer as it better explained the reason behind the answer, but nonetheless I've voted up yours as it was still correct.